# 2 div seperated by a border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create two centered div, which are seperated by a border like this.

Didn't know how to insert the border between the two div.
the two div are clickable.

[image]

```css
.homescreen-content {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    max-height: 100% !important; 
  }
.goto {
    margin-top:20%;
    left:0;
    height: 100% ;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

.no {
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
   width: 100% !important;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="homescreen-content" scroll="false">
  <div (click)="open()" class="goto">
      <h2>TITLE 1 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <hr class="border">
  <div (click)="open()" class="no">
      <h2>TITLE 2 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a `div` instead of `hr` with `height` as `border-width`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50627897/9674579

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Fabio, you could replace your `<hr>` tag with a `<div>` and set the height of the `<div>` to be the thickness of the border you want.

```css
.homescreen-content {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    max-height: 100% !important; 
  }
.goto {
    margin-top:20%;
    left:0;
    height: 100% ;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

.no {
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
   width: 100% !important;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.border {
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="homescreen-content" scroll="false">
  <div (click)="open()" class="goto">
      <h2>TITLE 1 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div (click)="open()" class="no">
      <h2>TITLE 2 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add border using CSS, look my CSS carefully !

```css
.homescreen-content {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    max-height: 100% !important; 
  }
.goto {
    margin-top:20%;
    left:0;
    height: 100% ;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    
    border-bottom : 15px solid white ;
}

.no {
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
   width: 100% !important;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    
    border-top : 15px solid white ;
}
```

```html
<div class="homescreen-content" scroll="false">
  <div (click)="open()" class="goto">
      <h2>TITLE 1 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div (click)="open()" class="no">
      <h2>TITLE 2 CENTRED</h2>
      <p>SOME CENTRED TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can change border color,

```
Border : 15px solid red ;
```

You can also change border type,

```
Border : 15px dotted blue ;
```